# What steps are needed to troubleshoot adding a new primary LCD TV as a monitor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi, display-resolution

Machine setup:

- Lenovo TS 440 ThinkServer
- Xeon E3-1225v3 cpu,
- a GeForce TITAN X (pre pascal) GPU with HDMI out and Ubuntu 16.04.

I got everything working with a Samsung 1080p monitor (model S27E510C).  Installed latest NVidia drivers (v 375?) and was able to play steam games without any problems.

I wanted to see everything working on my LG 75 inch LCD 4k TV and was hoping that just plugging the server to the TV and it all would just "work".  Alas, no.

Note: I am *not* trying to support two displays, I just wish to be able to switch between them from time to time.  When I plug the 75 inch LCD TV to the server,

What's happening (symptoms):
I do get an initial GUI sign-on screen for Ubuntu but when I try to login, the screen goes black and then I get the login screen again.  I tried changing the screen resolution in `~/.config/monitors.xml` but no change.  I tried running `xrandr` but I get:

> Can't open display (no display number)

Note:  there is a built-in Intel graphics card on the motherboard so maybe there is some conflict there.

I also tried issuing a `get-edid` and that tells me that "Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 or DDC2 transfers".

So can anyone suggest what steps I need to follow to get things working on my LCD TV?  How to troubleshoot?  I'd like to be able to set things up so that I can easily switch between monitor and TV without a lot of hassle.  I suppose I could try running the NVidia driver install tool again, but would rather not.  I certainly shouldn't have to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: I broke it out for TL;DR crowd.  Does that look better?  And yes, I looked long and hard throughout this forum and on other Linux forums before posting this question.  I tried to do due diligence.  Most relate to trying to setup DUAL displays.  That's not what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

I think I created my own problem.

Just before plugging into the new LCD TV, I had done a "sudo apt update / upgrade" and after doing some research later realized that hammered my Nvidia proprietary driver settings. To fix and use the new TV I did the following (from memory so excuse me if I missed noting a step):

I.   Unistalled / Reinstalled Nvidia driver

```
 a.  Dropped to non X command line (ctrl + alt + f1)
 b.  Stopped the x-server (sudo service lightdm stop)
 c.  Ran the nvidia-uninstall tool (nvidia- <tab>)
 d.  Ran the Nvidia driver install (sudo sh NVIDIA-xxx.run)
```

II.  Rebooted box

III. I got a desktop that was virtual and too big so to adjust I

```
 a.  Right-clicked on the desktop
 b.  Selected settings app
 c.  Clicked on the "Display" setting app
 d.  Turned OFF the built-in Intel graphics display so that my GPU was driving the screen
 e.  Adjusted the artifact size (don't remember what it was called) to make things readable at hi-rez.
 f.  Edited ~/.config/monitors.xml
 g.  In the <output name="HDMI-0"> section, edited the width / height 
     to match MAX resolution of my 4k TV 

    <width>3840</width> 
    <height>2160</height>
```

And (to the joy of my kids) we can now play hi-res Steam games in the family room on the big screen TV!

Answer (score 0):

"Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 or DDC2 transfers" that answers your question for yourself right there. I believe your graphics card won't display on that monitor based on that error. Perhaps because your laptop gpu was not meant to display in 4k.

Comment: Machine is NOT a laptop (not a ThinkPad).  It is an Intel Xeon E3 ThinkServer with a quite powerful last gen GeForce TITAN X GPU (12 GB RAM, 5.2 CUDA compute capability) so it should be able to produce SOMETHING to the TV I would think.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your original comment. I think it should produce something on the TV as well. If your card has multiple display outputs on it I would try plugging it in to whichever monitor is usable for you now as well as your 75 inch LCD and go to system settings for your monitors. It should give you the option to switch between the two monitors from there.